# how to run two async methods simultaneously?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

i'm ashamed to admit i've been using python's asyncio for a long time without really understanding how it works and now i'm in a pickle. in pseudo code, my current program is like this:

```
async def api_function1(parameters):
    result = await asyncio.gather(*[some_other_thing(p) for p in parameters])

async def api_function2(parameters):
    result = await asyncio.gather(*[some_other_thing2(p) for p in parameters])    

def a(initial_parameters): 
    output = []
    data = asyncio.run(api_function1(initial_parameters))
    output.append(data)
    while True: 
        data = asyncio.run(api_function1(get_parameters_from_data(data)))
        output.append(data)
        if some _condition is True:
            break
    return output 

def b(initial_parameters): 
    output = []
    data = asyncio.run(api_function2(initial_parameters))
    output.append(data)
    while True: 
        data = asyncio.run(api_function2(get_parameters_from_data(data)))
        output.append(data)
        if some condition is True:
            break
    return output
```

a() and b() get data from two different rest api endpoints, each with its own rate limits and nuances. i want to run a() and b() simultaneously.

what's the best/easiest way of structuring the program so a() and b() can run simultaneously?

I tried making a() and b() both async methods and tried to await them simultaneously, i.e. something like

```
async a(initial_parameters):
    ...


async b(initial_parameters):
    ...


A = await a(initial_parameters)
B =  await b(initial_parameters)
```

but it didn't work, so based on the docs, I'm guessing maybe i need to manually get the event_loop and pass it as an argument to a() and b() which would pass them to api_function2() and api_function2(), and then close it manually when both tasks are donw but not really sure if i'm on the right track or how to do it.

Also open to better design pattern for this if you have one in mind

Comment: restructuring as you have one or other ```await asyncio.gather``` effectively blocks. A single ```await asyncio.gather``` for both sets of parameters would be better. The location of ```asyncio.run()``` within logic I find unusual. An ```async def main():``` puts your high level code into async operation in a way that feels more natural, at least for me, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you can't nest calls to asyncio.gather.  If you want to run a() and b() simultaneously, you must make both of them coroutines.  And you can't use asyncio.run() inside either one of them, since that is a blocking call - it doesn't return until its argument has completed.  You need to replace all the calls to asyncio.run() in a() and b() with await expressions.  You will end up with something that looks like this:

```
async def api_function1(parameters):
    return await asyncio.gather(*[some_other_thing(p) for p in parameters])

async def api_function2(parameters):
    return await asyncio.gather(*[some_other_thing2(p) for p in parameters])    

async def a(initial_parameters): 
    output = []
    data = await api_function1(initial_parameters)
    output.append(data)
    while True: 
        data = await api_function1(get_parameters_from_data(data))
        output.append(data)
        if some _condition is True:
            break
    return output 

async def b(initial_parameters): 
    output = []
    data = await api_function2(initial_parameters)
    output.append(data)
    while True: 
        data = await api_function2(get_parameters_from_data(data))
        output.append(data)
        if some condition is True:
            break
    return output

async def main():
    a_data, b_data = asyncio.gather(a(initial_parameters), b(initial_parameters))
    
async def main():
    task_a = asyncio.create_task(a(initial_parameters))
    task_b = asyncio.create_task(b(initial_parameters))
    a_data = await task_a
    b_data = await task_b
    
asyncio.run(main())
```

This is still pseudocode.

I have given two possible ways of writing main(), one using `asyncio.gather` and the other using two calls to asyncio.create_task.  Both versions create two tasks that run simultaneously, but the latter version doesn't require you to collect all the tasks in one place and start them all at the same time, as `gather` does.  If `gather` works for your requirements, as it does here, it is more convenient.

Finally, a call to `asyncio.run` starts the program.  The docs recommend having only one call to `asyncio.run` per program.

The two api functions should return something instead of setting a local variable.

In asyncio the crucial concept is the Task.  It is Tasks that cooperate to provide simultaneous execution.  Asyncio.gather actually creates Tasks under the hood, even though you typically pass it a list of coroutines.  That's how it runs things in parallel.